# javascript/DOM select object onchange function call not working but inline HTML does

Tags: javascript, firebase, drop-down-menu

So I am using firebase to design a site and calling data from the database to populate a select function..

i have a js file that has a lot of firebase things such as authentication happening after the html/DOM is completely loaded, with some declared functions at the bottom.

When setting up this dropdown menu, I am retrieving items from the database to populate it, then doing this line of code-

```
dropDown.setAttribute("onchange", changeTable());
```

to add the onchange listener on it, in my code, when onclick is triggered/the select items value changes, it repopulates a table with items from the database based on what was selected.

The problem is, this function is called once then won't trigger again. above it, I have code that works like this -

```
classes.orderByKey().on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
    var z = document.createElement("option");
    z.setAttribute("value", snapshot.key);
    var t = document.createTextNode(snapshot.key);
    z.appendChild(t);
    dropDown.appendChild(z);
});
```

which populates the dropdown menu with items from the database, when this happens, the function changeTable() is called once (I am guessing because there is a new value selected when the items are added), then no matter how many times i change the select option it doesnt do anything, however, if I change the setAttribute part by instead doing setAttribute("onchange", changeTable()) with the function call, and I instead place the actual code from that function as a string / inline code like this-

```
dropDown.setAttribute("onchange", "console.log("hello")");
```

then the inline code that is there works perfectly? why is the function call messing up for me and only firing off once but if I use inline code it works? Id like to tidy up my code and do a function call if possible...

as a side note that is related to this issue, As you see above I am adding items to the dropdown menu ordered by key, I have a table that is populated based on which option is chosen, but I need to populate the table after all the options are added to the select element, but I do that with a similarly asynchronous function using orderByValue calling info from the database, and to do that, I need to get the current selected value from the dropdown. Is there anyway I can have this code wait until all the values are added to the dropDown to execute?

Comment: `dropDown.setAttribute("onchange", changeTable());` is wrong. Do not use setAttribute, use addEventListener, and you are calling the method and assigning what it returns, you are not binding to that method.

Answer (score 2):

You should not be using setAttribute to bind event handlers, you should be using addEventLister(). Second you are calling the method and assigning what it returns to the event.

```
dropDown.addEventListener("change", changeTable);
```